# How to group by elements of a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that resembles this:

```
81883       2011000011  ...  [South Sturgeon, Creek]
81884       2011000022  ...        [Meadowood]
81885       2011000016  ...   [South, Portage]
81886       2011000011  ...  [North Sturgeon, Creek]
```

I want to groupby rows that have common words (words are values of the Locations column splitted by ',') from the last column (named Locations): for example in the mentioned example I want to groupby Creek, and when no common words are found the rows will be kept as is (or better joined as string)
I tried using:

```
 def get_grp(list_current_row, df,column_location): 
    rows_index_to_groupby = [] 
    for string_element in list_current_row: 
        for idx,row in enumerate (df[column_location].values): 
            if row != list_current_row and string_element in row: 
                rows_index_to_groupby.append(idx) 
    return rows_index_to_groupby


 grouped_dataframe = resulting_dataframe.groupby(lambda x: [resulting_dataframe[column_location][i] for i in get_grp(x, resulting_dataframe,column_location)] )
```

The desired output would be:

```
Locations
Creek             0  Creek       81886       2011000011  ...
                  1  Creek       81883       2011000011  ...
South, Portage    2  South, Portage      81885       2011000016  ...
Meadowood         3  Meadowood       81884    2011000022
```

Comment: Updated it to differentiate the two, South, Portage is two words (split by ',')

Comment: I'm missing something: you want to group by Creek, but the output shows grouping by individual words of the full input column, *except* that South Sturgeon is not there, and "South, Portage" are still together. Why "South, Portage" as one item, but not "South Sturgeon, Creek"? And still: what happened to South Sturgeon; why is that not listed (ditto North Sturgeon of course)?

Comment: `South Sturgeon, Creek` and `North Sturgeon, Creek` are both in `Creek` and so I want to groupby `Creek`

Comment: You don't group by a column value; you group by a column.

Comment: So let me try and rephrase: if you have identical entries in the values of the Location column, then you want to somehow merge these values, probably into a multi-index of sorts.

Comment: `But should it always be the last word/token?`  yes, because the location is better represented in the final word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not exactly what is asked, the following might get what you want. This simply extracts the last element of the location values and assigns that to the index:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'number': [81883, 81884, 81885, 81886], 
    'date': ["2011000011", "2011000022", "2011000016", "2011000011"],
    'location': [["South Sturgeon", "Creek"], ["Meadowood"], ["South", "Portage"], ["North Sturgeon", "Creek"]],
})


df.index = df.location.str[-1]
print(df)
```

yields

```
           number        date                 location
location                                              
Creek       81883  2011000011  [South Sturgeon, Creek]
Meadowood   81884  2011000022              [Meadowood]
Portage     81885  2011000016         [South, Portage]
Creek       81886  2011000011  [North Sturgeon, Creek]
```

Now you can simply get all Creek entries with e.g.

```
df.loc['Creek']
```

Since the index has the same name as a column, "location", you may want to rename the index:

```
df.index.names = ['primary_location']
```

and for grouped operations, you can then do e.g.

```
df.groupby('primary_location')['number'].sum()

primary_location
Creek       163769
Meadowood    81884
Portage      81885
Name: number, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Seems to be OK, but how about a solution with `dataframe.groupby(someFunction)`, is it possible in this case?

Comment: what if I don't want to change the index of the dataframe, can I create another column instead ?

Comment: @user1319236 You can keep the original index around, with `df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays((df.index, df.location.str[-1]), names=['index', 'primary_location'])`.

Comment: You don't have to create a new index, although it feels logical in this case. You can just create an extra column "primary_location" instead of an index,  and group on that.

Comment: `dataframe.groupby(someFunction)` doesn't really make sense to me. `dataframe.groupby(<column or list of columns>).<somefunction>` does. But, what do you want to do with that; it's not your actual question? And I've already given an example of such a thing with `.sum()`.

Comment: it is OK but ideally I would have wanted a solution using lambda function in groupBy... Also the example I did with groupBy takes the current row and the column name : `get_grp(list_current_row, df,column_location)` I don't know if that helps correct it?

Comment: Could you show us how it could be also done with `dataframe.groupby(<column or list of columns>).<somefunction>`